# A non-empty closed proper set in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $A$ be a non-empty closed proper set in a metric space $\langle M,\rho\rangle$.
>
> Let $x_0 \in M-A$, and let $\beta = \inf \{ \ \rho (x_0,a) \mid a \in A\}$.
>
> Show that $\beta > 0$.

I know the requirements for a metric space but I don't know where $\beta$ comes into this problem. Any help on what I'm not seeing here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\beta$ is defined within the problem statement (loosely speaking, we can call it the distance from the point $x_0$ to the set $A$), and the goal is to show that $\beta > 0$. Can you clarify what exactly is your question?

Comment: I guess it'd be I don't know how to really go about the inf of a metric space

Comment: In fact, $\{\rho(x_0,a) \mid a \in A\}$ is a set of real numbers, so $\rho$ is the inf of a set of real numbers. Moreover, it's a set of nonnegative real numbers since metrics are never negative. Therefore, $\beta$ must be $0$ or $> 0$. Can you show that if $\beta = 0$, then $x_0 \in A$.

Comment: i understood the first part of that but if beta is equal to 0 does that mean that the distance between x and a is 0?

Comment: Since $M\setminus A$ is open, there is an open ball $B$ of radius say $\alpha$, centre $x_0$ such that $B\subset M\setminus A$.  Let $\beta=\alpha/2$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $\beta$ is basically the "distance" from $x_0$ to the set $A$. Unfortunately, sometimes we have $\beta=0$ even though $x_0$ isn't actually in $A$ - for example, take $A=(0, 1)$ and $\beta=0$. Then $x_0\not\in A$, but there are elements of $A$ "arbitrarily close" to $x_0$, so $\beta$ - the infimum (over $a\in A$) of the distances from $x_0$ to $a$ - is zero.

Of course, in that example, $A$ is not closed. The question is asking you to show that, if $A$ is closed, this silly behavior can't happen - if $x_0\not\in A$ then $\beta>0$.

So, towards solving the problem: in the example above ($x_0=0, A=(0, 1)$), what exactly made $\beta=0$? And how would $A$ being closed prevent that from happening?

Comment: thank you for the help on this problem noah!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $inf\{\rho(x_0,a), a\in A\}=0$. This implies that for every integer $n>0$, there exists $a_n\in A$ such that $\rho(x_0,a_n)<1/n$. This implies that the sequence $a_n$ converges to $x_0$ thus $x_0\in A$ since $A$ is closed. Contradiction. done.

Comment: i think if i would have started with trying to show that beat=0 i would have understood it a little easier. Thank you very much for the help!